# Java Unnecessary Overlaying of Images

Tags: java, image, swing, paint, paintcomponent

Hello Java Developers,

I've never encountered this scenario so far. This scenario is:
(To make the scenario general for readers, lets have this illustration.)
We have this `Box.png` and `Circle.png` declared:

```
private final URL IMG1_DIRECTORY = Main.class.getResource("/res/Box.png");
private final URL IMG2_DIRECTORY = Main.class.getResource("/res/Circle.png");
```

Under our constructor:

```
try {
    box = ImageIO.read(IMG1_DIRECTORY);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Our catchblock here
}

try {
    circle= ImageIO.read(IMG2_DIRECTORY);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Our catchblock here
}

currentImg = box;
```

With the `paint` method, the box is drawn to our `JPanel` as shown in our `Illustration 1`.

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(currentImg, DEFAULT_LOCATION, DEFAULT_LOCATION, null);
}
```

Through a certain event, `mousePressed` in this example the Image will be changed.

```
@Override
public void mousePressed( MouseEvent e ) {
        currentImg = circle;
        repaint();
}
```

The desired output is shows in our `Illustration 2`. Unfortunately, the result happens to be the `Illustration 3`.
The question was:
- Why is the result happens to be both image overlaying each other?
- Another thing, if I have a code that will repaint the image to circle ( From `Illustration 3` ) the box will just overlay the `circle` image.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You've failed to call `super.paint`, which, apart from a whole bunch of other important stuff, clears the graphics context
2. You should rarly need to override `paint`, it's normally preferred to use paintComponent, but make sure you call `super.paintComponent`

The graphic context is a shared resource and tends to be re-used between repaints, that means, because you didn't clear the graphics context when you painted, you've got the previous "state", which then paint over

Comment: Hello @MadProgrammer, please elaborate why should I use paintComponent over paint.

Comment: @MichaelArdan `paint` will paint the component as well as its children.

Comment: @MichaelArdan paint calls paintComponent, paintBorder and paintChildren, by overriding paint, you've basically stripped out the components capabilities to actually render all its layers.  Paint also sets up double buffering, which will prevent updates from flickering

Comment: @MichaelArdan you might also like to have a read through [Perfoming Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Comment: Anyway, what would be the result of not calling super.paintComponent()?

Comment: @MichaelArdan One of the jobs paintComponent does is clears the graphics context by filling it with the background color of the component

Answer (score 6):

Override `paintComponent()` (not `paint()` method).

Call `super.paintComponent(g)`

Comment: Hello StainslavL, I have tried your method before posting this question. Didn't work for me.

Comment: @MichaelArdan then post SSCCE to illustrate the problem

Comment: Please pardon my previous comment. I have tried the paintComponent() but I wasn't able to call super.paintComponent(g). This answer worked for me

Comment: What are the result of not calling super.paintComponent(g)?

Answer (score 2):

you need to repaint the screen. Java carrys on paining until you tell it not to or tell it to restart.

`super.paintComponent(g);`

will allow this to reset. Alternativly you need to just redraw a square over the part you want to blank out

`g.clearRect(x,y,width,height)`

will let you just clear a rectangle with its upper left corner x,y

update this code

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
g.drawImage(currentImg, DEFAULT_LOCATION, DEFAULT_LOCATION, null);
}
```

to allow for the changes. You should also be over riding paintComponent